# How to write a format statement to read real numbers from a file and store them in an array?

Tags: fortran, format, precision

I am writing a program to read real numbers (up to 16 digit after decimal) from text files and store them in arrays.
Here's a simple program showing what i want to do:

```
program readexcel
    dimension array(10,10)   
    Open(unit=10,file='aa.txt',status='old')
    read (10,*) ((array(i,j),j=1,10),i=1,10)
    pause
end program
```

aa.txt file (10x10):

```
1.12312374123123,2.12312312345,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
2,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1,6.1,7.1,8.1,9.1,10.1
3,2.2,3.2,2,5.2,6.2,7.2,8.2,9.2,10.2
4,2.3,3.3,4.3,5.3,6.3,7.3,8.3,9.3,10.3
5,2.4,3.4,4.4,5.4,6.4,7.4,8.4,9.4,10.4
6,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5,7.5,8.5,9.5,10.5
7,2.6,3.6,4.6123456789101112,5.6,6.6,7.6,8.6,9.6,10.6
8,2.7,3.7,4.7,5.7,6.7,7.7,8.7,9.7,10.7
9,2.8,3.8,4.8,5.8,6.8,2,8.8,9.8,10.8
10,2.9,3.9,4.9,5.9,6.9,7.9,8.9,9.9,10.9
```

This code works,but using the asterisk * (default) will only read four digits after the decimal because the array is of type real.
I tried to use double precision arrays but this solution is not practical, since in the real program i have so many arrays, and so many subroutines that are using these arrays.
What I need help with is to write a format statement where i can define the width of the variable, as well as the number of digits.

Comment: If you want 16 significant figures you're going to have to use "double precision" or quite possibly more - on almost all machines default real numbers can only represent up to around 7 significant figures, and if you are using them you just can not get more, internally that's all they are represented as. Oh, ALWAYS use Implicit None, don't use pause, learn about Fortran kinds rather than "double precision" - if you use the later feature of the language carefully the change you sat is "not practical" should in fact be trivial